# what does that mean <td class="bodytext2">

Tags: html, css

I see it in the jsp pages and not sure what it means?

```
<td class="bodytext2">
```

it causes text to display blue, and I don't want it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a CSS entry somewhere for bodytext2 which determines the style of table cell. This entry will look like ".bodytext2" or some variant with selectors in front of it, and it can be on the page, linked on the page, or linked in anything linked on the page. There's a good chance that the CSS class was applied programmatically in a "dumb" sort of way. Go learn CSS and a server-side language and all will become clear.

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of any context, it appears to be a custom class assigned to the <td> element. You'll have to look in the CSS to see what it does.

Comment: where is the CSS in my project? I mean where is it usually stored? thx

Comment: surf to the site with Firefox+firebug. when in the relevant page, open the net tab in firebug and see where the CSS comes from. Sometimes a simpler approach would be to view page source and see the actual link to the css (and thus know where it is).

Comment: Itay Mosav this really should have been an answer and not a comment.

Comment: hmm...It doesn't answer his question, just show A way to find the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Search your project for .css files. More than likely you are going to find a reference to one towards the top of your .jsp file. Inside the .css file you will find a reference to .bodytext2. This is where styles (like the blue font color) you mentioned are defined.